# How can I check if the user is playing the game for the first time?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to show a text for the first time running like "Hi, my name is NAVI." and then when the player will start the game again the next time it will another text for example "Welcome back."

[image: Main menu]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [player prefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) is probably the easiest solution, though definitely not the only one*.

Due to the lack of boolean playerpref I usually opt to use `SetInt`/`GetInt` instead, but that's personal preference. You could also do it with a string or float.

```cs
private void Start()
{
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HasLaunched", 0) == 0)//Game hasn't launched before. 0 is the default value if the player pref doesn't exist yet.
    {
       //Code to display your first time text
    }
    else
    {
       //Code to show the returning user's text.
    }
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HasLaunched", 1); //Set to 1, so we know the user has been here before
}
```

Playerpref stores values between sessions, so the next session will still have "HasLaunched" set to `1`. This is however stored on the local device. so users can manually reset it if they'd really want to.

If you ever want to show the "first launch" text again, simply set `HasLaunched` back to zero, or delete it altogether with `DeleteKey("HasLaunched");`

*There are plenty of alternative solutions, like storing it in a config file locally, or using a remote database (this would be required if you don't want users to be able to reset it). They would however come down to the same principle. Setting a value to true or 1 somewhere, and checking that value on launch.

Comment: Note for readers: do not store arbitrary game state information in PlayerPrefs. *For this usage* its probably fine as resetting the first-run flag is relatively innocuous and serves only to display a message or to offer the player the option to play the tutorials, which the user may wish to revert irrespective of game saves.

Comment: To further @Draco18s point, storing game state to PlayerPrefs is typically bad practice because PlayerPrefs are incredibly easy to change. They are meant to store "player's preferences" (AKA anything that a player is expected to be able to directly modify), and not progression data.

Comment: Agreed with both, it *shouldn't* be used to store actual game state info, Although I think storing something as simple as this is "alright". That's why I left the footnote saying that if you don't want your users to be able to change this data to use something that tracks it remotely like a database instead.